# Composition API problems with start a function when mounted. No data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

What do I want to achieve:

- The form is only loaded if processingData is available.
- Currently the form is not loading because processingData is not available

The problem I am currently running into is that when I load the application (in the browser, or possibly f5), no data is visible within `processingData`. If I modify the application and rebuild again in the editor, I see the correct value. I can't get out anymore..

Create.vue (FILE)

```
<template>
   <FormModal v-if="processingData" :processingData="processingData" @gateway="saveForm" />               
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.el-input--suffix .el-input__inner {
  background-color: #f5f8fa;
}

.el-input__inner {
  background-color: #f5f8fa;
}
</style>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import FormModal from '@/components/forms/FormModal.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: "",
  components: {
    FormModal,
  },
  setup() {
    const form = ref({});
    const componentName = ref('SalesTable');
    const processingData = ref(null)

    const store = useStore();
  

    const components1 = computed(() => {
      return store.getters.getComponents;
    });


    function loadComponent() {
      console.log(store.getters.getComponents) // Shows nothing (Only after I update the code and rebuild is, it shows data)
      console.log(components1.value) // Shows nothing (Only after I update the code and rebuild is, it shows data)
      const components = components1.value;
    
      let i;
      for (i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        if (components[i].name == componentName.value) {
          processingData.value = components[i];
        }
      }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
       loadComponent() 
    })

    return {
      form,
      processingData,
      components1,
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: where do you dispatch the action that fills the state?

Comment: Before the hole application loads. If I `console.log(components1)` (just after `const components1`) it shows always data. No matter what.

Comment: As I can see now, this function is being fired before the application is loaded. This is very wierd in my opinion. Has this something to do with Composition API?

Comment: Sorted it out! This view (Create.vue) was loaded outside the v-if structure inside my Layout.vue.